# Flutter Dart widget list item Alphabetical from index

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, widget, listitem

this list is from index (mysql) i would like to output my list [index] alphabeticaly this is little tricky for me should i use a package ? or is that any easy way to solve that ?

```
   Widget listItem(int index) {
    return Card(
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
        elevation: 4.0,
        child: IntrinsicHeight(
            child: InkWell(
          child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  VerticalDivider(
                    color: primary,
                    thickness: 2,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                      child: Text(
                        cityList[index].cityName!,
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                ],
              )),
          onTap: () {
            if (!mounted) return;

            catVisible = true;

            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) =>
                        SubCategory(cityId: cityList[index].id, catId: "")));
          },
        )));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To sort just use listName.sort();

Comment: can you show me an example how  ?